# Анимация при изменении внутреннего маршрута, Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Использую Vue, Vue-router. Необходимо запускать анимацию при изменении маршрута включая внутренние маршруты. Но анимация срабатывает только при изменении простых маршрутов.

Те при переходе '/course' -> '/lessons' анимация отрабатывает, а при переходе '/lesson/1' -> '/lesson/2' анимация не происходит. Как это можно изменить?

```
<transition name="slide" mode="out-in">
    <router-view></router-view>
</transition>
```

Comment: я думаю, для данной проблемы можно привести воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score -1):

Анимации не происходило, тк внутренним маршрутам соответствовал одинаковый компонент. Чтобы эти компоненты были разные нужно задать уникальный ключ. Можно сделать данный ключ, зависящим от пути маршрута.

```
   <transition name="slide" mode="out-in">
            <router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
        </transition>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [рекомендациями по написанию хорошего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Укажите не только решение проблемы, но и то, почему данное решение работает и является верным.